# Base constructors inherited to derived class?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have always thought that base class constructors/destructors/friends are not inherited by derived class. This link confirms this : 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-4/.

I was also aware that we can write base class constructors in the initialization list of derived class initializer list.

Having said that: I tried to check my skills today about it. But I failed to guess the output of this program.

```
#include<iostream>

class A {
  int x, y;
  public:
    A(int a = 0, int b = 0) : x(a), y(b) {
      std::cout << "A ctor called" << std::endl;
    }
    void print_A() {
      std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
      std::cout << "y = " << y << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
  int z;
  public:
    // I knew that A member can be initilized like this.
    B(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0) : z(a), A(b, c) {
      std::cout << "C ctor called" << std::endl;
      // I was not aware about that. 
      A(b, c);
    }
    void print_B() {
      std::cout << "z = " << z << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
  B b(1, 2, 3);
  b.print_A();
  b.print_B();
}
```

Output :

```
A ctor called
C ctor called
A ctor called
x = 2
y = 3
z = 1
```

Couple of questions:

- If constructors/desctructors/friends are not inherited from base, how can class 'B' is able to access constructor of class 'A' here.
- How come you get this output? How come two constructors of 'A' have been called.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is faulty. This:

```
// I was not aware about that. 
  A(b, c);
```

doesnt initialise the A member of B, it (notionally at least) creates a temporary, nameless local variable in the body of the constructor, somewhat analogous to if you had said:

```
  A a(b, c);
```

The constructor for A is a public member, so anything can call it.

Answer (score 1):

> If constructors/desctructors/friends are not inherited from base, how can class 'B' is able to access constructor of class 'A' here?

"Not inherited" does not mean "inaccessible to the derived class". A derived class can certainly reference a base constructor. `B`'s constructor does it twice:

- The first access is in the initialization list
- The second access is in the body of `B`'s constructor; it creates a temporary object

Inheriting a constructor would mean that users of `B` would be able to access `B(int, int)`, which they cannot do<sup>*</sup>.

> It seems like a constructor call. Why does it create a temporary object?

Consider this method:

```
void foo(const A& a);
```

A common way is to call it like this:

```
A a(1, 2);
foo(a);
```

but C++ also lets you call it without creating `A` on a separate line:

```
foo(A(1, 2));
```

In this case C++ creates a temporary object, and passes `foo` a reference to it. When you write

```
A(1, 2)
```

C++ also creates a temporary object for you by calling its constructor.

> How come two constructors of 'A' have been called.

The constructor is invoked twice; that is why you get the output.

<sup>*</sup> C++11's `using` mechanism allows you to achieve an effect [very similar to constructor inheritance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors), provided that you follow specific rules.

Answer (score 0):

the constructor is called by the every time  A(b, c) is called;

you are calling it on line

```
B(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0) : z(a), A(b, c) {
```

and you are calling it inside the b constructor

```
// I was not aware about that. 
      A(b, c);
```

the code works as intended

Answer (score 0):

> If constructors/desctructors/friends are not inherited from base, how can class 'B' is able to access constructor of class 'A' here.

You mean on these lines?

```
  // I was not aware about that. 
  A(b, c);
```

It isn't "accessing the constructor" in the sense you think. It just creates (and immediately discards) an anonymous temporary `A` in the body of the constructor function.

> How come you get this output? How come two constructors of 'A' have been called.

Because you created two instances of `A`: the base-class subobject of `B b`, and the anonymous temporary.

Here's an easy experiment to verify this, with the following logging:

```
// in A
A(int a = 0, int b = 0) : x(a), y(b) {
  std::cout << "A::A @" << static_cast<void*>(this) << std::endl;
}
~A() {
  std::cout << "A::~A @" << static_cast<void*>(this) << std::endl;
}

// in B
B(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0) : z(a), A(b, c) {
  std::cout << "B::B @" << static_cast<void*>(this) << std::endl;
  A(b, c);
}
~B() {
    std::cout << "B::~B @" << static_cast<void*>(this) << std::endl;
}
```

I get output something like

```
A::A @0xffec7054
B::B @0xffec7054
A::A @0xffec704c
A::~A @0xffec704c
x = 2
y = 3
z = 1
B::~B @0xffec7054
A::~A @0xffec7054
```

See that the instance address of the second `A::A` is different from the first (so it's a different object), and it's followed by an `A::~A` (because the anonymous temporary goes immediately out of scope).

---

Notes:

1. If you could "call the constructor" as you suggested originally, it would look something like

   ```
   auto subobject = static_cast<A*>(this);
   new (subobject) A(b, c);
   ```

   and would be very wrong. The `A` subobject of `b` was completely constructed when it's own constructor completed, before the body of `B`'s constructor starts. You can't just re-create a new object in the same space, what would happen to the old one?

   This may seem trivial, but for objects with dynamically-allocated resources, it would be a serious bug. It's not allowed.
2. You wrote your initializer list `: z(a), A(b, c)`, but should be aware the base-class subobject will be constructed before the derived-class members are initialized. That is, those two things will happen in the opposite order to what you wrote. It's not (necessarily) an error, but it's worth knowing.

Comment: But why, It seems like a constructor call. Why does it create a temporary object.

Comment: Creating an object _does_ call the constructor. That's _how_ the object is constructed. And `A(b,c)` is just the same as `A a(b,c)` except you didn't give the new object a name. Compare the expression `new A(b,c)` which also constructs an object in newly-allocated memory (in that case the resulting `A*` pointer will usually be saved in a named variable, but the object itself doesn't have a name).